# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'teams' of undefined thrown - Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm running into this issues when I'm running `ng test`. It compiles fine, and `ng build --prod` runs fine. I don't even see those variables with that name just the Observables but the have a $ infront of the variables.

**QUESTION UPDATED**

> "@types/jasmine": "2.8.9",
>       "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
>       "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
>       "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
>       "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
>       "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
>       "karma": "~1.7.1",
>       "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
>       "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
>       "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
>       "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
>       "protractor": "^5.4.2",
>       "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
>       "tslint": "~5.9.1",
>       "typescript": "~2.7.2"

Thi is all I see when Karma opens
[image]

My command line 
[image]

**PARENT TEST file**

```
describe('MembersComponent', () => {
  let component: MembersComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MembersComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({})
      ],
      declarations: [MembersComponent, ModalComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: Store, useClass: StoreStub }]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MembersComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**CHILD TEST FILE**

```
describe('ModalComponent', () => {
  let component: ModalComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ModalComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ModalComponent],
      imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, StoreModule.forRoot({})],
      providers: [Store]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ModalComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Comment: `this.store` is undefined. Usually, services are mocked in tested. What does your mock look like?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten I don't really know how to do that. I'm new with Karma

Comment: Share your Karma test code.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten done

Comment: You are mocking NgRx `Store` by using RxJS `BehaviorSubject`. BehaviorSubject does not provide the same API. It does not have methods like `dispatch` and `select`. See its [documentation](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject). Use Store mocks from NgRx as described in the [Testing](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing) article.

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten I don't even want to test it. My other parts of the state are not giving me issues just this one. the other components test fine too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't even want to test `store` then try below below:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

class StoreStub {
    select(val: any) {
        if (val === 'whatever action you have defined for RacingSelectors.selectMembers') {
            return of<Member[]>([
                {}, // create dummy member objects
            ]);
        } else if (val === 'whatever action you have defined for RacingSelectors.selectTeams') {
            return of<Team[]>([
                { firstName: '' },
                { lastName: '' },
                { jobTitle: '' },
                { team: '' },
                { status: '' }, // create dummy member objects
            ]);
        }
    }
    dispatch() {}
}
```

and in `spec` file:

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({})
      ],
      declarations: [MembersComponent, ModalComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: Store, useClass: StoreStub}]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create', () => { 
        component.ngOnInit(); 
       expect(component).toBeTruthy(); 
   });
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for taking your time to help me out. Seems like the problem is on 'teams' I have changed your code to be an array of Team[] instead of memebers and I'm still having the same issue

Comment: @PatricioVargas I created it as an array of members because `$members: Observable<Member[]>;` has `Member[]` type. I think `dispatch of undefined` error must have been resolved. I can't see any code related to `teams`. that code seems to be giving `can't read teams of undefined`. Is it something inside `RacingActions` class ?

Comment: sorry I erased the line ```  $teams: Observable<Team[]>;``` by accident in my questions. I have added it again. I have noticed that the dispatch problem is gone. the only one that keeps appearing twice is ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'teams' of undefined thrown``` I have updated my question

Comment: @PatricioVargas : I still can't see `.teams` in your provided code. Can u add screenshot of entire error. it shows the line number where this error is coming. This is not happening from your provided code for sure

Comment: Yep!! I don't see that .teams in that component not even in the html page. I think it's because ```.teams``` is part of my state. my state is as follow ```{members: Member[], teams: Team[], selectedMember: Member}```

Comment: @PatricioVargas : But with my `StoreStub` the call should not go to `states`. We are overriding the main `store`. Also, Can you paste the entire error screenshot as I asked before. Also, is there any other child component which might be getting rendered while testing this component ?

Comment: Queston updated. I have added the whole image that from the debug in karma and uploaded the code for the child component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194145/discussion-between-shashank-vivek-and-patricio-vargas).